# Show Common Content In All Tabs - Ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, ionic-framework

I want to display some common content in all the ionic tabs and on tabs switch, i want to switch part of content and not the whole content.

Basically i have an image on which user does operations. That image must be included only once in the  template.

There are many tools divided on the basis of category. When a user selects a particular category, its tools are displayed.

So, i chose tabs-interface of ionic to display different set of tools. But the problem is that i am not able to find a common place where i can place that image and it should show in all tabs. How to achieve that? This is what i am doing.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-only">
    <ion-tab title="Home" icon-on="ion-ios-filing" icon-off="ion-ios-filing-outline">
        <!-- Tab 1 content -->
        <ion-content>
            <!-- common image -->
            <img src="tshirt.jpg">

            Dynamic Content Of Tab One
        </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="About" icon-on="ion-ios-clock" icon-off="ion-ios-clock-outline">
        <!-- Tab 2 content -->
        <ion-content>
            <!-- common image -->
            <img src="tshirt.jpg">

            Dynamic Content Of Tab Two
        </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Settings" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline">
        <!-- Tab 3 content -->
        <ion-content>
            <!-- common image -->
            <img src="tshirt.jpg">

            Dynamic Content Of Tab Three
        </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Any luck here? If you can, please share your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create like below:

```
<ion-content>
      <div class="abc">
        Dynamic Content Of Tab One
      </div>
</ion-content>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var common = $('.abc');
    $.each( common , function( key, value ) {
       $(this).prepend('<img src="tshirt.jpg">');
    });
});
</script>
```

There are so many methods to do this task:
Use [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

You may need little modification.

Comment: But this will insert 3 image tags into the HTML.